# Typeahead, react strap

Tags: reactjs

Using https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead

```
 this.state = {
      pset: 'C'
    };
```

...

```
  setValue = (key, value) => {
    const property = { ...this.state };
    property[key] = value;
    this.setState(property);
  };

  onTypeaheadChange = (key, arrVal) => {
    this.setValue(key, arrVal[0])
  };
```

...

```
<Typeahead
  id="1"
  onInputChange={e => setValue('pset', e)}
  onChange={(arrVal) => onTypeaheadChange('pset', arrVal)}
  selected={[this.state.pset]}
  options={['A','B']}
/>
```

I want to be able to have a pre-selected value, but not necessarily one of the options.

https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead/blob/master/docs/Usage.md#controlled-vs-uncontrolled

> Similar to other form elements, the typeahead can be controlled or
>   uncontrolled. Use the selected prop to control it via the parent, or
>   defaultSelected to optionally set defaults and then allow the
>   component to control itself. Note that the selections can be
>   controlled, **not the input value**.

What does this mean? I can't do what I want? Is there any workaround?

Comment: It means that you can set the `value` prop of `Typeahead` and store it in the parent component state like you are used to with e.g. a regular `input` element. [This part of the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) elaborates on the concept.

Comment: So value={this.state.pset} ? It's not working

Comment: Yes, that's right. The `react-bootstrap-typeahead` library doesn't support controlling the `value` like that.

Comment: Hm, wierd. Pretty crucial feature for many typeahead situations. You know any other library I can use?